# Top 10 sql query list

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

Good morning, I need assistance with generating a top 10 list. below is the created query however i'm unsure how to correctly implement the *ROWNUM* function.

```
SELECT * FROM
( SELECT CON_NAME, HIGHEST_QUAL FROM temp2 ORDER BY HIGHEST_QUAL DESC )
  WHERE ROWNUM = 10;
```

As when the query is run no data is produced however when i omit the *ROWNUM* all the rows are produced showing the data is there. Also when the *ROWNUM* is set to 1 only one row is produced.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where ROWNUM <= 10

Comment: when you get no data you have less then 10 results - because _**your**_ query shows only the tenth result ( `ROWNUM = 10` ) not 1 to 10 ( `ROWNUM < 11` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROWNUM` inside the subquery and reuse the aliased name with conditions as you like

*TOP 10 Highest*

```
   SELECT * FROM
    ( SELECT ROWNUM rnum, CON_NAME, HIGHEST_QUAL FROM temp2 ORDER BY HIGHEST_QUAL DESC )
      WHERE rnum <= 10;
```

*10th Highest*

```
   SELECT * FROM
    ( SELECT ROWNUM rnum, CON_NAME, HIGHEST_QUAL FROM temp2 ORDER BY HIGHEST_QUAL DESC )
      WHERE rnum = 10;
```

*Greater Than Fifth Highest, lesser than 9th Highest*

```
   SELECT * FROM
    ( SELECT ROWNUM rnum, CON_NAME, HIGHEST_QUAL FROM temp2 ORDER BY HIGHEST_QUAL DESC )
      WHERE rnum > 5 and rnum < 9;
```

Comment: Oh goodness I feel dumb, how did i overlook that. Thank you very much!